# json_serializer.DeserializeObject, immediate window, VS2017

Tags: c#, javascriptserializer, immediate-window

I am a c# beginner (but quite familiar with JavaScript), and I am learning by debugging example code. I have a question now regarding the "immediate window".

I set a breakpoint at

```
  (... nested object sent via JSON from some external javascript code ...)
var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var value_list = (IDictionary<string, object>)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(value);
```

Then evaluated the following in the immediate window

```
value_list
Count = 4
    [0]: {[type, msg]}
    [1]: {[settings, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]}
    [2]: {[hello, edge]}
    [3]: {[txt, notepad.exe]}

value_list["txt"]
"notepad.exe"


value_list["settings"]
Count = 2
    [0]: {[host, test.com]}
    [1]: {[port, 80]}
```

So far so good.

Then I tried

```
value_list["settings"]["host"]
```

But only got "error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'".

How can I print the value of host in the immediate window?

Comment: If you are just learning, ditch and forget that the class `JavaScriptSerializer` ever exister. Use the NewtonSoft.Json package, it has been the standard for a very long time

Comment: yes, JsonConvert is much better

Comment: JavascriptSerializer is an obsolete class introduced way back when AJAX first came out. Every stack since ASP.NET Web API uses JSON.NET, aka NewtonSoft.Json, instead. Just don't use JavascriptSerializer

Comment: Noted (and I saw the same advice in Microsoft's API documentation already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a strongly typed language.

You have

```
var value_list = (IDictionary<string, object>)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(value);
```

The `var` means that the type of the variable is determined by the compiler during compilation already. Because of the cast at the right side, the compiler determines this:

```
IDictionary<string, object> value_list = (IDictionary<string, object>)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(value);
```

So, `value_list` is of type `IDictionary<string, object>`. So, `value_list["settings"]` is of type `object`.

To see the value in the immediate window cast the intermediate result (which is of the type `object`) to the appropriate type.

```
((IDictionary<string, object>)value_list["settings"])["host"]
```

Comment: #1 works. Thank you! #2 does not work

error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

Although a reference has been added already. But this should be separate question. I just wanted to point out that #1 seems to be the "easier" solution.

Comment: @cscharf Yeah, I have deleted the second proposal from the answer. Using `dynamic` in the immediate window only works in projects where `dynamic` is already used in the actual project source (which one should not do except for very specific situations).

Comment: Got it. Thanks.